# skip split on (" ") if a digit is following to get an array using python/pyspark

Tags: python, regex, apache-spark, pyspark, split

want to create a new column based on a string column that have as separator(" ") and skip the split if a digit is following using python/pyspark :

**Inputs :**

```
"511 520 NA 611"
"322 GA 620"  
"3 321"
"334 344"
```

**expected Output :**

```
+Column           | +new column
"511 520 NA 611" | [511,520,NA 611]
"322 GA 620"      | [322,GA 620]
"3 321"         | [3,321]
"334 344"         | [334,344]
```

**try :**

```
data = data.withColumn( "newcolumn", split(col("column"), "\s"))
```

a condition on a regex is seems working but I don't know how to use it

Comment: Try `r"(?<=\d)\s+"`

Comment: If you skip the split when a digit is following then `"511 520 NA 611"` will end up as `["511 520",  "NA 611"]`.

Comment: I use it instead of \s" no result , in fact seems like it must have a condition before the split :/